# geefirth giving error "Error in matrix(x$id,ncol=1): 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r

I have a problem using `geefirth` from the `geefirthr` package to run a Firth-type GEE for correlated binary data. Subjects are nested within different centers.

```
 df <- data.frame(subject_id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
                 center_id=c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                 x1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), 
                 x2=c(0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.90,0.90,0.90,0.90,0.86,0.86,0.86),
                 x3=c(2.80,2.80,2.8,2.8,2.8,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.6,2.6,2.6),
x4=c(4.72,4.72,4.72,4.72,4.72,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.35,3.81,3.81,3.81,3.81,4.40,4.40,4.40), 
y=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1))

data(df)
geefirthr::geefirth(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, id=center_id, data=df, corstr="independence")
```

I receive the below error:
Error in matrix(x$id, ncol=1): 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

I tried the below and is.vector(df) returns TRUE. Any ideas on how to resolve?

```
df <- unlist(df)
df <- as.vector(df)
df <- as.vector(df$center_id)
```

Comment: Is this package available in CRAN

Comment: I ran your code and I don't have the error you gave. Additionally `data(df)` is not a right line of code

Comment: @akrun The package is available in CRAN and also on github here: https://rdrr.io/github/momenulhaque/geefirthr/

Comment: When I tried with R 4.1.1 using install.packages, it shows the message package not available in CRAN

Comment: @akrun I installed using ```remotes::install_github("mhmondol/geefirthr")```. However, ```available::available_on_cran("geefirthr")``` confirms available on CRAN with R 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved when using R rather than Rmd file.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.